# How to connect keyboard to button?

Tags: java, android, keyboard

In my application I have `EditText` and `Button` and for this `editText` I set **actionDone** for **`imeOption`**.
**My EditText code :**

```
<EditText            
    android:id="@+id/infoSerialFrag_rememberSwitchText"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/size30"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/infoSerialFrag_rememberSwitch"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:hint="7"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:maxLength="3"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:textSize="@dimen/font11" />
```

When open keyboard show me **Done** in **keyboard**.
For `Button` I set one method.
I want when click on **Done from keyboard**, work me such as `onClickListener` for my `Button`.

**My mean is :** when click on **Done** from keyboard, call method in `button.setOnClickLiostener{...}`

How can I it? please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code

```
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new EditText.OnEditorActionListener() {
       @Override
       public boolean onEditorAction(EditText v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
       if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
          view.performClick();
          return true;
       }
       return false;
       } 
   });
```

View is the button view name. You need to call **`performClick()`** method. this will execute the code which is available in **`onclick()`** call back method. Hope that answers your question

Comment: where is write my `button.SetOnClickListener` method code?

Comment: once you have written the code with click listener now you don't need to write again. Just use the button reference and call performCLick method